Error during compaction reported in logs, LEAK DETECTED: a reference ... was not released before the reference was garbage collected
There is a time-series data table in Cassandra 5.0 that uses a collection map type. During compaction, a memory leak error like the one below occurs. I am wondering about the solution.
If you can provide the exact error message or more details, I can assist you further in finding a solution.
[2024-08-10 17:00:55,814] [STORAGE] [ERROR] [Reference-Reaper]  Ref.java:243 - LEAK DETECTED: a reference (class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileHandle$Cleanup@1350358023:/data1/pp-data/cassandra/data/pp/tm_asset_data-3fdee2c055e811efbbb9ade82e603b4a/da-3gik_0m9d_2zt682gly48a602kk0-bti-Data.db) to class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileHandle$Cleanup@1350358023:/data1/pp-data/cassandra/data/pp/tm_asset_data-3fdee2c055e811efbbb9ade82e603b4a/da-3gik_0m9d_2zt682gly48a602kk0-bti-Data.db was not released before the reference was garbage collected
[2024-08-10 17:00:55,814] [STORAGE] [ERROR] [Reference-Reaper]  Ref.java:243 - LEAK DETECTED: a reference (class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileHandle$Cleanup@1350358023:/data1/pp-data/cassandra/data/pp/tm_asset_data-3fdee2c055e811efbbb9ade82e603b4a/da-3gik_0m9d_2zt682gly48a602kk0-bti-Data.db) to class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileHandle$Cleanup@1350358023:/data1/pp-data/cassandra/data/pp/tm_asset_data-3fdee2c055e811efbbb9ade82e603b4a/da-3gik_0m9d_2zt682gly48a602kk0-bti-Data.db was not released before the reference was garbage collected
[2024-08-10 17:00:55,814] [STORAGE] [ERROR] [Reference-Reaper]  Ref.java:243 - LEAK DETECTED: a reference (class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileHandle$Cleanup@2078760468:/data1/pp-data/cassandra/data/pp/tm_asset_data-3fdee2c055e811efbbb9ade82e603b4a/da-3gik_0m9d_2zt682gly48a602kk0-bti-Partitions.db) to class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileHandle$Cleanup@2078760468:/data1/pp-data/cassandra/data/pp/tm_asset_data-3fdee2c055e811efbbb9ade82e603b4a/da-3gik_0m9d_2zt682gly48a602kk0-bti-Partitions.db was not released before the reference was garbage collected
[2024-08-10 17:00:55,814] [STORAGE] [ERROR] [Reference-Reaper]  Ref.java:243 - LEAK DETECTED: a reference (class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileHandle$Cleanup@2078760468:/data1/pp-data/cassandra/data/pp/tm_asset_data-3fdee2c055e811efbbb9ade82e603b4a/da-3gik_0m9d_2zt682gly48a602kk0-bti-Partitions.db) to class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileHandle$Cleanup@2078760468:/data1/pp-data/cassandra/data/pp/tm_asset_data-3fdee2c055e811efbbb9ade82e603b4a/da-3gik_0m9d_2zt682gly48a602kk0-bti-Partitions.db was not released before the reference was garbage collected
[2024-08-10 17:00:55,815] [STORAGE] [ERROR] [Reference-Reaper]  Ref.java:243 - LEAK DETECTED: a reference (class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileHandle$Cleanup@2078760468:/data1/pp-data/cassandra/data/pp/tm_asset_data-3fdee2c055e811efbbb9ade82e603b4a/da-3gik_0m9d_2zt682gly48a602kk0-bti-Partitions.db) to class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileHandle$Cleanup@2078760468:/data1/pp-data/cassandra/data/pp/tm_asset_data-3fdee2c055e811efbbb9ade82e603b4a/da-3gik_0m9d_2zt682gly48a602kk0-bti-Partitions.db was not released before the reference was garbage collected
[2024-08-10 17:00:55,815] [STORAGE] [ERROR] [Reference-Reaper]  Ref.java:243 - LEAK DETECTED: a reference (class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileHandle$Cleanup@2078760468:/data1/pp-data/cassandra/data/pp/tm_asset_data-3fdee2c055e811efbbb9ade82e603b4a/da-3gik_0m9d_2zt682gly48a602kk0-bti-Partitions.db) to class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileHandle$Cleanup@2078760468:/data1/pp-data/cassandra/data/pp/tm_asset_data-3fdee2c055e811efbbb9ade82e603b4a/da-3gik_0m9d_2zt682gly48a602kk0-bti-Partitions.db was not released before the reference was garbage collected
[2024-08-10 17:00:55,815] [STORAGE] [ERROR] [Reference-Reaper]  Ref.java:243 - LEAK DETECTED: a reference (class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileHandle$Cleanup@2081245557:/data1/pp-data/cassandra/data/pp/tm_asset_data-3fdee2c055e811efbbb9ade82e603b4a/da-3gik_0m9d_2zt682gly48a602kk0-bti-Rows.db) to class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileHandle$Cleanup@2081245557:/data1/pp-data/cassandra/data/pp/tm_asset_data-3fdee2c055e811efbbb9ade82e603b4a/da-3gik_0m9d_2zt682gly48a602kk0-bti-Rows.db was not released before the reference was garbage collected
[2024-08-10 17:00:55,815] [STORAGE] [ERROR] [Reference-Reaper]  Ref.java:243 - LEAK DETECTED: a reference (class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileHandle$Cleanup@2081245557:/data1/pp-data/cassandra/data/pp/tm_asset_data-3fdee2c055e811efbbb9ade82e603b4a/da-3gik_0m9d_2zt682gly48a602kk0-bti-Rows.db) to class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileHandle$Cleanup@2081245557:/data1/pp-data/cassandra/data/pp/tm_asset_data-3fdee2c055e811efbbb9ade82e603b4a/da-3gik_0m9d_2zt682gly48a602kk0-bti-Rows.db was not released before the reference was garbage collected
[2024-08-10 17:00:55,815] [STORAGE] [ERROR] [Reference-Reaper]  Ref.java:243 - LEAK DETECTED: a reference (class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileHandle$Cleanup@2081245557:/data1/pp-data/cassandra/data/pp/tm_asset_data-3fdee2c055e811efbbb9ade82e603b4a/da-3gik_0m9d_2zt682gly48a602kk0-bti-Rows.db) to class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileHandle$Cleanup@2081245557:/data1/pp-data/cassandra/data/pp/tm_asset_data-3fdee2c055e811efbbb9ade82e603b4a/da-3gik_0m9d_2zt682gly48a602kk0-bti-Rows.db was not released before the reference was garbage collected
[2024-08-10 17:00:55,815] [STORAGE] [ERROR] [Reference-Reaper]  Ref.java:243 - LEAK DETECTED: a reference (class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileHandle$Cleanup@2081245557:/data1/pp-data/cassandra/data/pp/tm_asset_data-3fdee2c055e811efbbb9ade82e603b4a/da-3gik_0m9d_2zt682gly48a602kk0-bti-Rows.db) to class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileHandle$Cleanup@2081245557:/data1/pp-data/cassandra/data/pp/tm_asset_data-3fdee2c055e811efbbb9ade82e603b4a/da-3gik_0m9d_2zt682gly48a602kk0-bti-Rows.db was not released before the reference was garbage collected

I tried changing the GC options to ZGC and G1GC, but it didn’t help.

Thanks for posting on Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

The LEAK DETECTED messages are pretty harmless because the Reference-Reaper has detected the leaks and released the references so it is doing its job.
It is unfortunate that they are logged at ERROR level instead of INFO or DEBUG because they are safe to ignore unless there are thousands of references which are not getting released and the node is running out of file descriptors. Cheers!
